# Equation of a line passing through points (cosθ, sin θ) and (cos Φ, sin Φ).

Tags: geometry

My solution to the above question gives slope of the line(m) as:

```
m= (sinΦ - sinθ)/(cosΦ - cosθ) = -cot(Φ/2 + θ/2)
```

And the equation thereupon is:

```
y = -cot(Φ/2 + θ/2).x + c
```

The value of c comes out to be:

```
c= -cot(Φ/2 + θ/2).cos Φ - sin Φ

 (on putting in the co-ordinates of second point)
```

Is the expression for 'c' correct? I have some doubts regarding that.

Post-Script:
*There were no 'Straight-line' tags*

Comment: Looks to me like you’ve got a sign error, but you should check your own work by plotting the results for a few interesting values of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking the trig identities this looks like a mostly correct approach.
$$y=mx+c \rightarrow m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

For finding $c$ few details are provided. I would normally plug in one of the points and solve for $c$. It appears that you may have attempted this?

$$ \sin\Phi = m\cos \Phi+c$$
$$ c =   \sin \Phi - m \cos\Phi$$
seems you may have a sign issue with your choice of $c$

Answer (score 3):

For such a question, I think it's worth having a geometrical view.

Let $\alpha:=(\theta+\Phi)/2$.

Take a look at the following picture :

[image]

Triangle $AOB$ being isosceles, vector $\binom{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}$ (in red) bissects angle $AOB$ therefore is orthogonal to vector $\vec{AM}=\binom{x- \cos \Phi}{y-\sin \Phi}$ where $M(x,y)$ is any point of straight line $AB$. This orthogonality means that the dot product of these two vectors is zero. As a consequence, the equation of straight line $AB$ is :

$$(x- \cos \Phi)\cos \alpha+(y-\sin \Phi)\sin \alpha=0$$

It remains to expand this equation into :

$$x \cos \alpha+y \sin \alpha=\underbrace{\cos \Phi\cos \alpha+ \sin \Phi\sin \alpha}_{\cos(\Phi-\alpha)}$$

i.e.,

> $$x \cos \alpha+y \sin \alpha=\cos \beta$$
>   where $\beta:=\Phi-\alpha=(\Phi-\theta)/2$ (half angle AOB).

Answer (score 0):

Use the line formula below

$$(x_2-x_1)y-(y_2-y_1)x = x_2y_1 - x_1y_2$$

for the two given points (cosθ, sin θ) and (cos Φ, sin Φ),

$$(\cos Φ -\cos θ)y- (\sin Φ -\sin θ) x  = \cos Φ \sin θ -\cosθ \sin Φ = -\sin(Φ -θ)$$

Use the trigonometric identities

$$\cos Φ -\cos θ=-2\sin \frac{ Φ+ θ}{2} \sin \frac{ Φ- θ}{2}$$ 
$$\sin Φ -\sin θ=2\cos \frac{ Φ+ θ}{2}\sin \frac{ Φ- θ}{2} $$
$$\sin(Φ -θ) = 2 \cos \frac{ Φ- θ}{2}\sin \frac{ Φ- θ}{2}$$

to eliminate the common factor $2\sin \frac{ Φ- θ}{2}$ and express the line equation as,

$$\sin \frac{ Φ+ θ}{2}y
+ \cos \frac{ Φ+ θ}{2}x=\cos \frac{ Φ- θ}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

A sketch shows that we need half-sum and half-difference of angles $ (Φ ,\theta ) $ HS and HD (bisector/its pedal perpendicular) respectively in polar-normal form of a straight line which is the correct choice needed here. So we have

$$ x \cos HS + y \sin HS = \cos HD $$